# Как ускорить работу Asyncio в Python?

Tags: python, многопоточность, asyncio

Моя задача - отправить 300-400 запросов за 5 секунд. Но получается отправить 100 и даже меньше.
Вот мой код:

```
    #выше основной класс программы
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click() #нажимаю на кнопку через селениум

    now = time.time()
    sec = now + 5 

    while now < sec and self.place:
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(self.send_request(url2, data, headers))) #создание запросов
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
        now = time.time()
        counter += 1
        
    print(counter)

    [await t for t in tasks] #Метка

async def send_request(self, url, data, headers):
    date = datetime.now()
    async with self.session.post(url, json=data, headers=headers) as response:
        try:
            json_body = await response.json()
            
            self.result += str(json_body) + '\n'
        except: self.result += str(traceback.format_exc()) + '\n'
```

Там, где я написал "Метка" программа работает очень долго, на столько долго, что я не дожидаюсь завершения и закрываю. Однако это не проблема, хотя неприятно... Проблема в том, что количество запросов слишком мало. Наверное, я в библиотеке asyncio использую не то, что нужно.
Запросы должны отправляться один за другим, где-то раз в 10 миллисекунд

Comment: Твоя ошибка в том, что ты не видишь разницы между многопоточностью и асинхронностью. Asyncio снижает простой интерпретатора при ожидании чего бы ни было (можно сказать, что увеличивается "плотность" вычислений). В то время как тебе для увеличения количества запросов нужна многопоточность, вот только в питоне она не настоящая из-за GIL и подобные задачи нужно переносить на мультипроцессинг - когда потоки работают на разных процессах интерпретатора питона.

Comment: Ок. То есть мне нужно переписать программу под multiprocessing, верно?

Comment: @cauf Не совсем так. GIL мешает только CPU-bound операциями. Отправке HTTP запросов (IO-bound операций) GIL не препятствует.

Answer (score 5):

Асинкио режет функцию на кучочки по слову await и выполняет новые кусочки пока эвейтит другой.

первый момент - стартуй по сто запросов, а не по одному:

```
while now < sec and self.place:
    for _ in range(100):
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(self.send_request(url2, data, headers))) #создание запросов
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    now = time.time()
    counter += 100
```

Они стартанут при await asyncio.sleep(0). А в твоем случае соединения устанавливаются по одному.

`[await t for t in tasks] #Метка` - тут при первом исключении всё повалится, этот генератор замени на

```
await asyncio.wait(tasks)
```

В оптимизации дальше: Тут один запрос - убери aiohttp вообще. Сформируй одно тело и пуляй в сырой сокет.

Тело http запроса выглядит так:

```
POST /ipc HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.117.9:1900
Accept-Language: ru-ru;q=1, ru;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36 OPR/73.0.3856.344
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 30

param=123&param=456
```

Comment: Понял, попробую. Но я не понял вот это "Сформируй одно тело и пуляй в сырой сокет."

Comment: @Jairman Думаю, имелось ввиду то, что, раз запросы одни и те же, то можно подготовить последовательность байт вида `b'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n*HEADERS*\r\n\r\n*BODY*\r\n` и отправлять её в обычный TCP сокет, соединенный с хостом. Вместо того, чтобы использовать обвязку в виде `requests`, которая делает то же самое.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов честно говоря, не делал так никогда

Comment: @Jairman Так мало кто делал, потому что это изврат :) Жертвуем удобством, размером в слона, ради производительности, размером со спичку.

Comment: В общем стало лучше, поэтому спасибо за ответ. Но всё-таки не так работает, как хотелось бы(